# skip asking for allow info sharing in openid

Tags: openid

i am using php-openid library.
i request email address from providers(Yahoo! and Google) to return back to me to check in my tables. when the user enters user and password to get authenticated with Yahoo! or Google,the provider asks user to allow sharing info.
some think like this:
Click "Agree" to sign in to mysite.com using your Yahoo! ID and allow sharing of Yahoo! info.

You are sharing the following:
useremail@yahoo.com

is it possible to skip this step?

Comment: hmm, is it not necessary to have authorization for that kind of information? anyone using openid could get my personal information if I use openid authetification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **[immediate mode](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor28)** (`checkid_immediate`), the provider will not interact with the user at all, and will thus skip that step.  But that means if the user is not logged in to their provider, or the user has not previously authorized their provider to give information to you, the login will not succeed.

Any OpenID provider with any concern for their users' privacy (which certainly includes Yahoo and Google) will never release the sort of information you're asking for without explicit permission from the user, which requires asking them.  In some countries this is mandated by law.  So no, you cannot get information without ever having to ask the user if it's okay.